# Adding image on dynamically created Button in Silverlight

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, silverlight, button, media

I am creating the button in silver light dynamically as

```
                HistoryButtton = new Button();
                HistoryButtton.Content = "History";
                HistoryButtton.Height = GetPercentageValue(TotalHeight, 8);
                HistoryButtton.Width = GetPercentageValue(TotalHeight, 15);
```

I tried this solution

```
    ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/history.png", UriKind.Relative)); 
    HistoryButtton.Background = brush;
```

But its not working.
I also tried this solution

```
   Uri uri = new Uri("/Images/history.png", UriKind.Relative);  
   BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
   Image image = new Image();
   image.Source = imgSource;
   HistoryButtton.Content = image;
```

But this solution also not working.  Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your Uri first parameter to be like this 
"/SolutionName;component/Images/history.png"

replace SolutionName with your Solution name.

Answer (score 0):

The question and one of the other answers here helped me with the same problem, but I still struggled with this for awhile (actually, more than awhile) because of some really simple things that I missed.  Here is the complete code that worked for me:

```
Dim b As New Button
Dim uri As New Uri("/<project name>;component/<path to image>", UriKind.Relative)
Dim imgSource As New Imaging.BitmapImage(uri)
Dim image As New Image()
image.Source = imgSource
b.Content = image
```

Two things that kept me from figuring this out sooner:

1. `<project name>` is the name of the project where the image resides, which may not be the same project the code resides in.
2. `"component/"` is a literal string (and is not a folder in the project).  My image file's "Build Action" is set to "Resource".

So if your project name is "MyProject", your image name is "MyImage.png", and the image resides in the folder "MyFolder" in "MyProject", the correct string to pass to the Uri constructor is:

```
"/MyProject;component/MyFolder/MyImage.png"
```